# Are inputs in separate forms sent when a submit button is hit?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a page in php that takes rows from a database, displays them, and then give the viewer a chance to upvote or downvote a specific entry. Here is a snippet:

```
echo("<form action=\"vote.php\" method=\"post\"> \n");
echo("<INPUT type=\"hidden\" name=\"idnum\" value=\"".$row[0]."\">");
echo("<INPUT type=\"submit\" name=\"up\" value=\"Upvote.\">  \n");
echo("<INPUT type=\"submit\" name=\"down\" value=\"Downvote\"> ");
echo("<form/>\n");
```

The problem is when I hit a submit button, the value for idnum that gets sent is based on the one farthest down it seems. So my questions is, when a submit button is pressed, are the values for all inputs on a page sent?

Comment: I'd like to comment that echo is not a function (ie it should not be echo(...)) it is a statement so echo should be used as: echo "text"
Second It would be easier to read if you just did this: ?><form action="vote.php" method="post">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="idnum" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your form tag isn't closed properly. You have `<form/>`, but it should be `</form>`.

This makes the entire page a form so it sends all the inputs. With a form that is closed properly though, it will only send the inputs within the form tags that the pressed button was in.

Answer (score 4):

While this wouldn't have helped with this particular issue, I would recommend not mixing your markup with your logic wherever possible. This is quite a lot more readable, and quite a lot more editable as well:

```
<form action="vote.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="idnum" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="up" value="Upvote.">
    <input type="submit" name="down" value="Downvote">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your form is not closed properly. Use `</form>` instead of `<form/>`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your html is that you should have `</form>`, not `<form/>`.